# A question on Baire spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We know that if $X$ is a Baire space and $(F_n)$ is a sequence of closed sets with empty interior then $\cup_n F_n$ has also empty interior. Now, suppose $V$ is a nonempty bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ ($m\geq1$) and $\overline{V}$ is the closure of $V$. We know that it is a Baire space. My my question is : if $(F_n)\subset \overline{V}$, such that the interior $int_{\mathbb{R}^m}(F_n)$ of each closed set $F_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is empty. Can we say that the interior of the union $\cup_n F_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is empty?

Comment: Why would this *not* follow from being Baire? Add your reasons for doubt...

Comment: I don't follow your question. You simply written what Baire space means in case of $\mathbb{R}^m$, which btw is a Baire space. Also I don't understand what role your $V$ and $\overline{V}$ play here, since you ask about interiors with respect to $\mathbb{R}^m$ (and since $\overline{V}$ is closed then each $F_n$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$).

Comment: Henno Brandsma. Since $\overline{V}$ is a subspace topology, my understanding is that $int_\overline{V}(\cup F_n)$ is empty. But in my question, the interior is taken not relative to the subspace topology but to the topology itself.

Comment: @freakish. But the interior relative to $\overline{V}$ and that relative to $\mathbb{R}^m$ are not the same.